# Autoconf how to build static binary

Tags: makefile, arm, cross-compiling, autoconf

I do cross-compile in my PC, and I want to build a static link binary. In order to run it on the target board without adding any shared library.
When compile a single file, I know I can use "-static" to build a binary without any shared library.
e.g.

```sh
$ aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o hello hello.c -static
$ file hello
hello: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked,
```

But when I use autoconf in the open source project, I can't build the binary static.
I have tried the following command, but failed:

```sh
$ ./configure --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --enable-static --disable-shared LDFLAGS="-static"
```

Is there any one know how to build a static binary with autoconf?